# How to run profvis so it show runtime for each line of a function from a package without rewriting the function as input?

Tags: r, profiling, profvis

Right now it seems like profvis requires re-writing the function

```
profvis({fun<-function(...) { ... return(...) } })
```

But if we only pass the function evaluation to profvis it will compress the whole function into one line

```
profvis(fun(...))
```

Is there a way to profile the function line by line without re-writing the whole script as input?